# Singleton Superclass

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton

I've been reading a bit on the singleton concept. While not fully understanding it, I'd like to have my instance getter in my base class.

For example, my class base class `RepositoryBase` will have the following method:

```
private static RepositoryBase _instance;
public static RepositoryBase Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new RepositoryBase();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Does this actually make sense? I believe that when a new child class (take for example `UserRepository`) inherits `RepositoryBase`, what it is still getting when retrieving `Instance` is an instance of the general class `RepositoryBase` and not an instance of `UserRepository`.

Is there any way I can make it such that `Instance` automatically returns the child class, while still remaining in the base class? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with a generic base class

```
abstract public class RepositoryBase<T>
    where T : RepositoryBase<T>, new()
{
    public static readonly T Instance = new T();
}

public class SpecificRepository : RepositoryBase<SpecificRepository>
{
}
```

Then use it like this

```
var obj = SpecificRepository.Instance;
```

Comment: But that is not really a singleton, but nothing more than a global variable.

Comment: @EricSchaefer: It is another way of implementing a singleton. Since the static variables are initialized the first time you access a member, it will still be lazy created. The oo-patterns are general ideas that do not specify specific implementations. At most they make suggestions.

Comment: Well, a statically initialized `public static readonly` variable isn't exactly a pattern, is it? I like the idea with the type argument, though.

Comment: @EricSchaefer Hm. I think that singletons are effectively read-only global variables. Could you please tell why do you think they are different? I am really interested in hearing your opinion on this.

Comment: @EricSchaefer: Are you confusing "patterns" (German: Muster, Entwurfsmuster) and "properties" (German: Eigenschaften)?

Comment: @Nikola: They look like read-only global variables but are more then that. The fact that they are global is just a side effect. Their purpose is to restrict the number of constructed instances.

Comment: The singletons and the singleton-pattern are not a variable (global or not), not a property and not a method. A singleton is a class which can be instantiated only once, respectively this very instance of it (the object). The singleton-pattern expresses the idea of having a class behaving like this but does not specify how it must be implemented.

Comment: You misunderstood me completely. I was saying that "statically initializing a `public static readonly` variable" does not really qualify as a pattern. Technically it has the same behavior as the singleton pattern, but it is still just a variable, although the use of a type parameter is pretty clever for making a static factory method polymorphous, which would be a pattern in its own right.

Comment: Neither does a property qualify as a pattern. The pattern is defined on a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Static members are not inherited, because they are static. That's why your take on it would not work anyway.

Comment: I can actually call it via `UserRepository.Instance`, so I guess to some extent you can still consider it inherited?

Comment: It is accessible, but you could not provide a special implementation in the derived class, which defeats the whole purpose of the inheritance in this case. You could just as well call ´RepositoryBase.Instance´.